# apt install gparted failed and it shows dpkg: error

Tags: apt, samba, gparted

i am about to install gparted and use the command:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

but what i got is :

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo apt-get install gparted
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gparted : Depends: gparted-common (= 1.0.0-0.1build1) but it is not going to be installed
 samba : Depends: samba-common (= 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) but 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.7 is to be installed
         Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) but 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.7 is to be installed
         Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) but 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.7 is to be installed
 samba-common-bin : Depends: samba-common (= 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) but 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.7 is to be installed
                    Depends: samba-libs (= 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) but 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.7 is to be installed
                    Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) but 2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.7 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

so i follow the advice, tab command:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

what i got is

```
root@ubuntu:~# sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ieee-data python3-bpfcc python3-netaddr
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  samba samba-common-bin
Suggested packages:
  bind9 bind9utils ctdb ldb-tools ntp | chrony smbldap-tools winbind heimdal-clients
The following packages will be upgraded:
  samba samba-common-bin
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 144 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,742 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,048 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 218079 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../samba_2%3a4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking samba (2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.7) over (2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/samba_2%3a4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.7_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/usr/bin/dumpmscat.dpkg-new' (while processing './usr/bin/dumpmscat'): Operation not permitted
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Samba is not being run as an AD Domain Controller: Masking samba-ad-dc.service
Please ignore the following error about deb-systemd-helper not finding those services.
(samba-ad-dc.service already masked)
Failed to preset unit: Unit file /etc/systemd/system/samba-ad-dc.service is masked.
/usr/bin/deb-systemd-helper: error: systemctl preset failed on samba-ad-dc.service: No such file or directory
nmbd.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
samba-ad-dc.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
smbd.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
Preparing to unpack .../samba-common-bin_2%3a4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.7_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking samba-common-bin (2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.7) over (2:4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/samba-common-bin_2%3a4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.7_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/usr/bin/dbwrap_tool.dpkg-new' (while processing './usr/bin/dbwrap_tool'): Operation not permitted
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Checking smb.conf with testparm
Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf
Loaded services file OK.
Weak crypto is allowed

Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE

Done
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/samba_2%3a4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.7_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/samba-common-bin_2%3a4.15.13+dfsg-0ubuntu0.20.04.7_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

the error it mentioned is

```
 unable to create '/usr/bin/dumpmscat.dpkg-new' (while processing './usr/bin/dumpmscat'): Operation not permitted
```

it is true ,and i can not even create file in that path by sudo

another problem is samba daemon

```
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
```

clealy show that Samba is not being run as an AD Domain Controller: Masking samba-ad-dc.service

i found `systemctl status samba-ad-dc.service` show

```
● samba-ad-dc.service
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit samba-ad-dc.service is masked.)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-10-26 20:02:51 PDT; 20min ago
   Main PID: 12975 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "daemon failed to start: Samba detected misconfigured 'server role' and exited. Check logs for details"

Oct 26 20:02:51 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Samba AD Daemon...
Oct 26 20:02:51 ubuntu systemd[1]: samba-ad-dc.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 26 20:02:51 ubuntu systemd[1]: samba-ad-dc.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 26 20:02:51 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Samba AD Daemon.
```

i had tried to reboot or other ways but they all falied

May I ask how to solve this problem? and how to install gparted.

Comment: It seems your filesystem might be read-only. You should find out why. The main problem here is that even root can't create files in `/usr/bin`